# Box Images with Grid Layout

Tags: css

Hello I'm trying to make a grid system
also to that:

```css
.grid_layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
  
 .item:nth-child(1),
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.gallery_item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .bg img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid_layout">
  <div class="item">
  <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Good but I have the following difficulty I need to put text under the small boxes like this:

[image]

But I don't know how I will be able to do with gridsystem like the image above
It probably wouldn't be possible the way I'm doing I tried to do it with the flex layout, but it is a big code.

Comment: you make the text like the first image. Each one will span 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`nth-last-child()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) and [`grid-column: span 2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column#Values) to achieve that.

```css
.grid_layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(1),
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.gallery_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item>.description {
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_layout">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="description">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="description">
      <p>consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="description">
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello is there any way for me to do only with 3 separate columns?

why would I probably have a problem using for each and popular with images and texts

Comment: @MykonSpt What do you mean "do only with 3 separate columns"? Can you explain more details?

Comment: in this case I thought to make a display: flex and spacebetween no justify content
and within each child a display grid